# How to slice the datetime into individual

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime

Example

```
2020-05-10 18:09:00
```

I need to make it

```
date = 2020-05-10
hour = 6
minute = 9
am_pm = PM

res.data.start_date = res.data.start_at.getDate();
res.data.start_hour = res.data.start_at.getHours(); 
res.data.start_minute = res.data.start_at.getMinutes();
```

I tried to use javascript get method but it does not work.

Comment: what is in res.data.start_at ?

Comment: To use Date methods you must first have a Date, it seems you have a string. So you might parse it to a Date first, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are fetching the data from some API (probably your backend).
You should first convert the string of the date into a `Date` object.

```js
const date: Date = new Date(res.data.start_at);
```

Then you could use the `Date` object methods such as `getDate()`, `getHours()`, etc.

*Your format has a small issue with the Date object - please read [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) to implement it appropriately.

Comment: The OP format is not one supported by ECMA-262 and returns an invalid date in some implementations, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)